# universal uitableview stretching issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios-universal-app

I am developing an universal(iphone/ipad) application. I am using uitableview in this application. table cell being draw using code. Now problem is that it can be fit either on iPad or iPhone from single code, If I put code only on single time.

To achieve this I need to put condition to check the device and then need to code 2 time, mean 1 for iphone and another for iPad to set its background images and frames of uilable etc..

This is looking rubbish and stupid job to me. Is there any way to achieve this goal by single code.
My code is as below. I am using xcode 4.2 ARC

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UIFont *fontName=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue LT 57 Cn" size:18.0f];
    UIFont *fontTitle=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue LT 57 Cn" size:12.0f];
    UIFont *grayLight=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    //UIFont *fontBold=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[arrEmails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",dic);
    int tot=4;
    NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"inbox_list%d",(indexPath.row%tot)+1];

    UIImageView *imgBg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-30, 10, 303, 70)];
    [imgBg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgBg];
    NSString *name=nameDisplayType==1 ? [[dic valueForKey:@"firstName"] stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [dic valueForKey:@"lastName"]] : [[dic valueForKey:@"lastName"] stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [dic valueForKey:@"firstName"]];

    UILabel *lblFirstName=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30 ,15,150,20)];
    [lblFirstName setText:name];
    [lblFirstName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblFirstName setTextColor:UIColorFromRedGreenBlue(162, 23, 25)];
    [lblFirstName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [lblFirstName setFont:fontName];
    [lblFirstName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFirstName];


    UILabel *lblEmailId=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,28,200,20)];
    [lblEmailId setText:[dic valueForKey:@"emailId"]];
    [lblEmailId setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblEmailId setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [lblEmailId setFont:grayLight];
    [lblEmailId setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [lblEmailId setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEmailId];




    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"date"]]; 
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
    NSString *formattedDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
    //NSLog(@"%@ formated:%@",[dic valueForKey:@"date"],formattedDate);

    UILabel *lblDate=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190,15,100,20)];
    [lblDate setText:formattedDate];
    [lblDate setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblDate setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [lblDate setFont:grayLight];
    [lblDate setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDate];


    UILabel *lblTitle=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,53,200,20)];
    [lblTitle setText:[dic valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblTitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [lblTitle setFont:fontTitle];
    [lblTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

    UIButton *btnViewGift=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(235, 55, 20, 20)];
    [btnViewGift addTarget:self action:@selector(btnViewGiftPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnViewGift setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnViewGift];


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    return cell;
}
```

Please help and give me some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing hardcoded agruments in frame, you can decide the frame dynamically using frame and bounds property of view. But you have to take care of each UI element.

Comment: Like try -UILabel *lblFirstName=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+someOffset ,self.view.frame.origin.y+someOtherOffset,self.view.frame.size.width/someWidthOffset, self.view.frame.size.height/someHeighOffset)]; -> and it will decide frame.